# json works with static file but not with dynamic php

Tags: php, json

Scratching my head on this one. I'm trying to convert json into an HTML list. If the json is in a static file, everything works. If I run a script it doesn't. If I use the output of the script in a static file, it works.

Code for handling the json:

```
<div id="placeholder"></div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
         $.getJSON('community.php', function(data1) {
               var output="<ul>";
               for (var i in data1.users1) {
                 output+="<li>" + data1.users1[i].Community_post_author + " " + data1.users1[i].Community_post_message + "--" + data1.users1[i].Community_post_time_stamp+"</li>";
               }
               output+="</ul>";
               document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
         });
     </script>
```

Code for creating json:

```
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($community_records)) {
  $rows[] = $r;
}

echo json_encode(array('users1' => $rows));
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

---

Per the comments (thanks!) here is the script output:

{"users1":[{"Community_post_time_stamp":"2013-06-25 06:41:13","Community_post_type":"community","Community_post_status":"live","Community_post_author":"MikeB","Community_post_message":"system check"},{"Community_post_time_stamp":"2013-06-22 08:27:34","Community_post_type":"community","Community_post_status":"live","Community_post_author":"fish2011","Community_post_message":"a apple a day does not keep the doctor away"},{"Community_post_time_stamp":"2013-06-22 08:26:40","Community_post_type":"community","Community_post_status":"live","Community_post_author":"grumpy","Community_post_message":"another day another dollar"},{"Community_post_time_stamp":"2013-06-22 08:26:10","Community_post_type":"community","Community_post_status":"live","Community_post_author":"devgirl","Community_post_message":"praise for this program "},{"Community_post_time_stamp":"2013-06-22 08:25:51","Community_post_type":"community","Community_post_status":"live","Community_post_author":"devguy","Community_post_message":"i'm 1 year sober today"},{"Community_post_time_stamp":"2013-06-22 08:25:28","Community_post_type":"community","Community_post_status":"live","Community_post_author":"raccoongrrll","Community_post_message":"Lost my phone charger"},{"Community_post_time_stamp":"2013-06-22 08:24:49","Community_post_type":"community","Community_post_status":"live","Community_post_author":"raccoongrrll","Community_post_message":"is there wifi at the clinic?"},{"Community_post_time_stamp":"2013-06-22 08:23:41","Community_post_type":"community","Community_post_status":"live","Community_post_author":"devguy","Community_post_message":"My girlfriend is driving me crazy"},{"Community_post_time_stamp":"2013-06-22 08:22:36","Community_post_type":"community","Community_post_status":"live","Community_post_author":"devgirl","Community_post_message":"Today's my birthday!!!"}]}

Comment: Look at the outputs of both - dynamic and static and compare them. Post here if possible

Comment: what is output of print_r(array('users1' => $rows)); ?

Comment: not enough information to suggest any thing, try to console.log(data1); to view the data structure of returned json object.

Comment: Code looks allright, but check that you didn't inadvertantly echo something before the json output. Browse to /community.php and have a look at the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `header('Content-Type: application/json')` to the PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code locally and just used a sample database - everything worked fine. As someone already mentioned: Ensure that there is no other 'echo' that gets mixed with your JSON data, and otherwise it might be the data returned by the mysql query.. maybe it's empty?